# How can I put a user in the superusers file?

Tags: debian, sudo

I have just installed the command `sudo` but when I use it returns that I am not in the sudoers file. What should I do?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudoers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login as root or `su` to get root prompt. Now type `visudo` and an editor will appear. Look for the line that says:

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Just mimic it and add your username (groupname?) below, like:

```
user ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

Comment: in sudo rules syntax, `user` is a username, `%user` is a group called "user".

I must remark that the rule ALL=(ALL) ALL means that the user having that rule may run *any* command from *any* terminal as *any* user of the machine. It should be taken in mind if concerned about security